# Nativescript resize image when new src is set?

Tags: image, nativescript

I have an image that is set with an initial src. When changing the src the image view retains its old size - meaning that the wrong size is used.

The image is set to `stretch="aspectFill"`.

Is there a update method I can use so the image view is resized?

Comment: Updating src with same path / image source may not reload the image. Try setting the src to null and set it back.

Comment: There is two different srcs that I alter between. Unfortunately it did not help to set it null before switching.

Comment: Please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I think I mixed up aspectFill and aspectFit. I was looking for aspectFit while having in fact set it to aspectFill: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/image. Meaning my smaller image filled a much larger area than intended.